# Jquery Traverse Down 2 Objects

Tags: jquery, traversal

I am using Squarespace so I am trying to inject a code to work with their existing code.  On this page, there are like 10 email addresses that appear next to photos with a consistent code between each photo and email that's generated by Squarespace.  I'd like to make it so that when I click on the email address (or `.summary-excerpt`), a link opens the default mail app like `<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send Mail</a>`  But I can't just write that code onto the page anywhere because of how the photos are aligned using their gallery feature.

First I tried to select the email with Jquery.  This is what I have so far:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.summary-excerpt:hover{
 cursor: pointer; 
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".summary-excerpt").click(function(){

      var link_to_email = this.p:nth-of-type(2).html();
window.location.href = link_to_email;
});


});

</script>
```

This is the tree I'm trying to traverse:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find` with the `nth-child(index)` selector

```
var link_to_email = $(this).find("p:nth-child(2)").text();
```

Comment: Got to it before me by seconds.  SO went "new answer!" just as I was about to click submit.

Comment: Hehe that happens to me so much :P

Comment: thanks!  i can accept this as the answer in 2 min. thanks again